# How can I get data from two different tables and have some interaction using PHP and MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to get some data from two separate tables from my database and multiply the results in a website.

There should be two inputs on the website to make this interaction (like search items).

The DB is on MySQL and I'm using PHP. Now it says **access forbidden**

```phtml
<body>

<?php
  if(isset($_GET['submit'])) {
    $sql = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM porteval, squarefeet WHERE Freguesia LIKE '%" . $_GET['Valorm2'] . "%'
           OR Metros Quadrados LIKE '%" . $_GET['M2'] . "%'");
  }
?>

  <form method="get" action="<?php $_SERVER['GET_SELF']; ?>">
    <tr>
      <td>Localização:</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="name" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Metros Quadrados</td>
      <td><input type="number" name="Valorm2" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Run" /></td>
    </tr>
  </form>
  </table>

<?php
  if(isset($_GET['submit'])) {
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
      echo $row['Valorm2'] * $row['M2'] . "<br />";
    }
  }   
?>

</body>
```

Comment: You need to echo the action attribute.

Comment: can you give me an example? sorry I'm noob

Comment: Change `<?php $_SERVER['GET_SELF']; ?>` to `<?php echo $_SERVER['GET_SELF']; ?>` is what Akintunde said/meant. Without the echo your action is blank.

Comment: Thanks! It still says "access forbidden"! :S my other searches are still going well! Can it be because Im trying to use two tables at the same time? Im using Xampp

Comment: You are open to XSS and SQL injections. `mysqli_query(` requires a connection. You should enable error reporting and monitor your logs. `Metros Quadrados` also will need to be in backticks, BUT you really should reconsider that column name. And finally `mysql_fetch_array` won't work with `mysqli`.

Comment: than, will it work? how can I do that @chris85? thanks

Comment: If you make those changes it will be closer. There are a few issues here, both in PHP and SQL.

Comment: `access forbidden` is a 403 or where does that come from? This code might not be relevant to your current issue.

Comment: where's your connection the database? Where´s  `mysqli_connect`? You are using `mysqli_query`but `mysql_fetch_array` you need to use just `mysqli`

Comment: Why are you using `$_GET` if your information is retrieved by `$_POST` and your `SELECT` is completely wrong, the best way would be using `JOIN` but you do like you are trying to, you need to reference the table. Right now I'm not even sure porteval and squarefett are your tables.

Comment: is a 403. It's only related to this search. The other select on the website connects to the database! @chris85

Comment: @DiéfaniFavaretoPiovezan I wrote mysqli_fetch_array and it still doesnt work!

Comment: @DiéfaniFavaretoPiovezan those are my tables.

Comment: Freguesia and Metros Quadrados are columns of which table? And if you colulmn name has spaces you should use `OR 'Metros Quadrados' LIKE` I strongly recommend you to change the column name to "MetrosQuadrados"

Comment: `mysqli_fetch_array` needs numeric or associative indexes. Take a look here how to use it: https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_fetch_array.asp

Comment: use the same page to check how to connect to database using `mysqli`

Comment: @DiéfaniFavaretoPiovezan I already changed to M2 thanks. I ll try to see... I'm still getting the 403 error. Thanks anyway

Comment: I believe the error is because your code has no connection to the database.